# Mathematica not simplifying an expression!

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I have the following matrix which can be checked to be zero by putting different values of parameter `x`. However, on applying FullSimplify, the desired result (zero matrix) is not obtained. How can we make *Mathematica* to do this simplification?

```
 a[x_] = {{(
   18 (-1 - x^2 + Sqrt[2 + 3 x^2 + x^4] Sqrt[1 - 1/(2 + x^2)]))/(
   x Sqrt[2 + 3 x^2 + x^4])}, {(
   18 (1 + x^2 - Sqrt[2 + 3 x^2 + x^4] Sqrt[1 - 1/(2 + x^2)]))/(
   x^2 Sqrt[2 + 3 x^2 + x^4])}, {(
   18 (1 + x^2 - Sqrt[2 + 3 x^2 + x^4] Sqrt[1 - 1/(2 + x^2)]))/(
   x^2 Sqrt[2 + 3 x^2 + x^4])}, {0}}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The matrix is guaranteed to be zero only if `x` is in reals; try for example `a[I]`.

To get the desired result, use `Assumptions`:

```
a[x] // Simplify[#, Assumptions -> x \[Element] Reals] &
(*{{0}, {0}, {0}, {0}}*)
```